# Get Rid of White Border around Tkinter Option Menu

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-menu

This may be a dumb question, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the white box surrounding my dropdown menu. I want the colored background to completely surround it. How do I achieve this?

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDmgT.png)

I'm just placing the menu in a label. self is in instance of a label.

```
drop=OptionMenu(self,clicked,"Option1","Option2",\
   command=lambda clicked:self.set_button(controller,clicked))
clicked.set("SELECT")
drop['menu'].config(background='black')
drop.place(relx=.3,rely=.85,anchor='n',relheight=.1,relwidth=.35)
```

Comment: Post your code, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: When you post code, please include the import statements and try to write a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for people to help you. If this is a `tkinter.OptionMenu`, then you cannot remove the border, on OSX the buttons are made with images so you cannot change the border or background color. If this is a `ttk.OptionMenu` you can do it by changing the theme to use one that allows to remove the borders, for instance 'clam'.

Comment: It may be the background of the parent label.  Include code of how to create the label.